# Kubernetes Django Disallowed Hosts

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy a Django app via Kubernetes. After creating my pod definition, LoadBalancer service, and routing DNS traffic to my LoadBalancer, I'm getting a `Disallowed Hosts error`.

I think I need to add the name of the LoadBalancer to my allowed hosts, but how do I do that when the LoadBalancer is created when I run `kubectl create -f service.yaml`?

pod.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test.example.com
  labels:
    app: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: my-image:1.0
    ports:
    - name: my-port
      containerPort: 8000
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mgmt-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: mgmt-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mgmt_reporting
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: What does your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` look like in `settings.py`?

Comment: You can add * for the dynamic part in your URL / ALLOWED_HOSTS: i.e. `*.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` or whereever your app is running

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to put the DNS name that I was routing traffic from into `allowed hosts`. The name of the LoadBalancer does not matter.

The DNS name is whatever you pointed at your load balancer. In my case, I created the DNS name `app.kubernetes.mydomain.com` Route53. This needs to go into `allowed hosts`